# Method with return? When should I use it?

Tags: java, return, global

I'm a beginner with java programming and I have a simple question:

When should I use return values? I understand the meaning and what I can do with it. But I wonder if I shouldn't always make global variables to work with.

Can you guys tell me when I should choose which option?

Comment: You need a return when you want to return something from your method. Simple!

Comment: Because global variables should be used only if the variables should be global :)

Comment: Like I said. I know what they are doing ;) But I could use a global variable too. Why shouldn't I go that way?

Comment: Global variables use is not  a good practice. Try to avoid it. Return values and local variables is always better.

Comment: i think by global variable you mean class attributes?

Comment: Ok, but why... "try to avoid it" is not a good reason for me to avoid it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is GLOBAL values should be avoided as much as possible. The reason  is global variable persists until the entire lifetime of that program. The GC (Garbage Collector) does not collect them until the program finishes(there may be some exceptions to this). But in contrast to this, local variables are eligible to be collected as soon as they fall out of scope. So the GC can collect them efficiently which leads to good memory usage.

So,
Generally, try to avoid using 'global' variables unless you have good reason to do so (e.g. the variable's contents are needed by more than one method in your sketch). This will help reduce the chances of inadvertently changing the contents of them in your code. So your second choice is one to avoid.

Some key points why NOT to use global variables:

1. It violates DATA ENCAPSULATION principle.
2. Lifetime is for whole program.
3. Messed up code if not carefully implemented

   For example, if you have two copies of your program running in the same VM, will they    share the static variable's value and mess with the state of each other.
4. Static variables represent state across instances which can be much more difficult to unit test. This is mainly because it is more difficult to isolate changes to static variables to a single test

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for :D Thank you!

Comment: I'd say the main reason to avoid global state is the fact that it doesn't work well with multi-threaded access (especially not if those different threads have nothing to do with each other, but happen to use the same method.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i was about to mention Mutlithreading too but then i realized that the question has been asked by a user who says 'I'm a beginner in JAVA'. So i kept it simple. :)

Comment: The other problem is readability: how will you sort through the hundreds of variables you have in your class? Whereas if you do int age = this.getAge() then you know easily what everything is doing and what values your variables should hold.